# HHKB key mapping different

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey

I have a HHKB hybrid type s keyboard.

The  \  |  key (top row, second from right) is not producing the characters backslash and vertical bar as printed on the key. Instead it is giving  # ~

How can I remap this with AutoHotKey?

I am running on a windows laptop  with UK regional settings. How do I make the key produce the characters on the key.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

resolved using a code solution: autohotkey

```
SC02B::Send, \
+SC02B::Send, |
+3::SendRaw, #
^4::SendRaw, €
!4::SendRaw, £
+2::SendRaw, @
+SC028::Send, ""
```